# ValidationExpression for RegularExpressionValidator to match only only the Cyrillic characters (bulgarianalphabet)

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression for my RegularExpressionValidator  to match only the Cyrillic characters (Bulgarian alphabet)

I tried the code

```
            rev.ValidationExpression = "^[/u0400-/u04FF]+$";
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unicode escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) starts with `\`, not `/`.

```
rev.ValidationExpression = "^[\u0400-\u04FF]+$";
```

In this case, the string (as seen by regex engine) is `^[Ѐ-ӿ]+$`. The escape sequences are interpreted by the compiler.

The same [character escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_escapes) are also valid in regex. So below 2 solutions are equivalent to the solution above:

```
rev.ValidationExpression = "^[\\u0400-\\u04FF]+$";
rev.ValidationExpression = @"^[\u0400-\u04FF]+$";
```

In these 2 cases, the string (as seen by regex engine) is `^[\u0400-\u04FF]+$`. The end effect is the same, since `\u0400` and `\u04FF` are interpreted by the regex engine to be `Ѐ` and `ӿ`.

Comment: @Tim: There is no need to escape ``\`` actually. Without doubling ``\`` up, we still got a character range with the unicode escape sequence in string literal.

Comment: One day you may want to print out an expression. I would rather see `^[\u0400-\u04FF]+$` than `^[?-?]+$`

Comment: @sln: It depends on how you output the expression and the output environment. I don't see any reason why one would print out a regular expression, though, except for debugging.